# multiselectable dropdown checkboxes using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I want to design a dropdownlist of checkboxes and make the checkboxes multi-selectable. I have used the below code,but I am unable to make multiple selections as the template refreshes each time I click on a checkbox,please suggest some ideas?

```
{   <ul class="status-select" class="status-select" ng-if="$index == selectedFilterIndex">
     <li ng-repeat="DataValue in filter.Data.Value">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="OnDropDownSelectionChanged(filter,DataValue)">
                        {{DataValue.displayText}}
     </li>
     </ul> 
}
```

Comment: Check this link http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/

Comment: hi,but they are using some "bower" library in there code,i want to implement in angular only..

Comment: @Bonyjose you don't need bower, there is an option to download `.zip` as well.

Comment: @Shekhar Swami where did the `{ }` came from in your edit?

Comment: @TJ Hey code was not formatted so i tried to format without adding anything. I am not aware of angularjs syntaxes. Is it required or not ?

Comment: @ShekharSwami Please don't make edits that you are not sure about. It is not required and not valid

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use directive like **angularjs-dropdown-multiselect**, which you can find very easily on internet

Here are some example:

1. ### **angularjs-dropdown-multiselect** - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaeldeongreen/22et6sao/9/)
2. ### **multiselectDropdown** - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prakash38/kvmkbb82/17/)
3. ### **Another example of angularjs-dropdown-multiselect** - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmvtmzmm/256/)

Code Snippet:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('exampleApp', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

myApp.controller('appController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.example13model = [];
    $scope.example13data = [{
      id: 1,
      label: "David"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      label: "Jhon"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      label: "Lisa"
    }, {
      id: 4,
      label: "Nicole"
    }, {
      id: 5,
      label: "Danny"
    }];

    $scope.example13settings = {
      smartButtonMaxItems: 3,
      smartButtonTextConverter: function(itemText, originalItem) {
        if (itemText === 'Jhon') {
          return 'Jhonny!';
        }

        return itemText;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```css
div, h1, a {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://bootswatch.com/slate/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/1.2.0/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js"></script>

<h2>
    Example of sytled angularjs-dropdown-multiselect  
</h2>

<a href="http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/">Source documentation</a>

<div ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="appController">

  <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example13data" selected-model="example13model" extra-settings="example13settings"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow the number 3 is pretty awesome! Remember not to use external scripts in your real project. Somebody might inject some crazy stuff in to your external lib...(man in the middle attack)

Comment: Hi, I want to add the button click event for this can you tell me how to set it. I have create event but it is not hitting can you resolve me

Answer (score 7):

a simple workaround that I've found is using [Angular Directives for Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#dropdown) using the `auto-close="outsideClick"` and the code should be like this:

```
<div class="dropdown" uib-dropdown auto-close="outsideClick" on-toggle="toggled(open)">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>Toggle</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu status-select" class="status-select" ng-if="$index == selectedFilterIndex" uib-dropdown-menu>
    <li ng-repeat="DataValue in filter.Data.Value">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="OnDropDownSelectionChanged(filter,DataValue)">
                      {{DataValue.displayText}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could go for Angular Material Design Library

[Select with Option Groups](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select)